# Ubuntu Server - Looking for software to take commands through email an execute them

Tags: email, postfix, plugins, mail-server, dovecot

I am looking for preferably Opensource software for Ubuntu Mail Server .

Requirement from software would be:

- Listening for incoming emails on a certain@email.address .
- In case the incoming email contained one of the predefined codewords, then the software would execute a very specific predefined command/script.
- Perhaps even command line parameter could be passed in either the same or separate emails.
- And perhaps COMMS could even require a termination by a last email.

Ideas are endles...
Manifesting them into a piece of software is clearly not as simple.

So please any of you who is aware of such thing out there...
It would be appreciated if you could let me know please.

This could be perfect for example to request certain logs, which the person has got no acces to trigger without SSH port open. Like for example Logwatch report genereated and emailed could be triggered from anywhere outside the LAN by email.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711075/ubuntu-15-10-server-do-i-need-an-email-client-on-my-server-for-it-to-get-read) was the closest I could find to the kind of software solution I am looking for, but not exactly a standard software.
It is good as an option to think about.

I am sure some of you will say things like it would probably be highly insecure...
I am interested in comments like that too, nothing's decided as I am not aware of existence of such software.

I am simply curious of hearing options from people who has got way more experience than I have, of how you would do this, if at all.

Comment: Instead of email, I would use a Telegram bot (safer method, because it requires special access) like this [botgram/shell-bot](https://github.com/botgram/shell-bot)

Comment: Mailman [https://list.org] does that to implement it's own functionalities. You may ask them how they achieve this.

Comment: GNU `gnats`, `https://www.gnu.org/software/gnats/` is a problem management system that accepts commands via e-mail, emacs or via the web.

Comment: @BinarWeb --- Telegram seems an iteresting thing, but I'll only ever go with self hosted stuff... on my own network. The idea is, to find software that could be used on my own Ubuntu servers. Thank you

Comment: @turbulence --- I'll email them, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @waltinator --- well, this `gnats` seems a very advanced piece of thing... this seems very promissing even after only reading docs for 2min. Thank you.